# 2007 Nissan Sentra Battery Fusible link keeps blowing

Tags: electrical

All, I have a 2007 Nissan Sentra that has been running me crazy. The entire power is out as a result of a blown battery fusible link. I'm on my 5th fusible link now but ive not installed it.

Please, could anyone offer their advise on what may be wrong that this fusible link keeps blowing upon trying to start this vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fusible link is really no different than a fuse. If it blows immediately on start up, you have a dead short to ground somewhere in that circuit. If it blows after some time, it's due to excessive current draw condition by some component in that circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes, it blows immediately upon start, so, the question is, how or where do I locate the dead short? Thank yoy again.

Comment: Also, where exactly do i ground?

Comment: What do you mean “where exactly do I ground”? Are you grounding the fusible link?

Comment: You start by getting a wiring diagram for that entire circuit. Then you trace the wire going from the fusible link, looking for any chaffed insulation between the link and the first component inthe circuit. If you don't find chaffed wiring or a rub through that would cause the wire to touch a ground point, then you disconnect the first component on the circuit and try again. If the new link doesn't blow, then you've confirmed that the short to ground is somewhere after the first component. Then you move on  to the next section of the circuit and repeat until you find the short.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your fuse link diagrams, they may help you find the short.

[image]

[image]